# SVG dimensions can't get larger to fit mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a silhouette I'm trying to use in a basic phone app.

Currently it is very small on screen, i want to increase it to take up more of the screen. However, when I change the dimension, it goes to being cut out on mobile, and in the bottom right hand corner.

This is the original SVG which works,

```
   function Silhoute({ success }) {
      return (
        <svg
          version="1.1"
          id="Capa_1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          x="0px"
          y="0px"
          viewBox="0 0 206.326 206.326"
          style={{ enableBackground: "new 0 0 206.326 206.326" }}
          xmlSpace="preserve"
          fill={success ? "#10B981" : "white"}
          className="h-full w-full opacity-50"
        >
          <g>
            <g>
              <path
                d="M104.265,117.959c-0.304,3.58,2.126,22.529,3.38,29.959c0.597,3.52,2.234,9.255,1.645,12.3
       c-0.841,4.244-1.084,9.736-0.621,12.934c0.292,1.942,1.211,10.899-0.104,14.175c-0.688,1.718-1.949,10.522-1.949,10.522
       c-3.285,8.294-1.431,7.886-1.431,7.886c1.017,1.248,2.759,0.098,2.759,0.098c1.327,0.846,2.246-0.201,2.246-0.201
       c1.139,0.943,2.467-0.116,2.467-0.116c1.431,0.743,2.758-0.627,2.758-0.627c0.822,0.414,1.023-0.109,1.023-0.109
       c2.466-0.158-1.376-8.05-1.376-8.05c-0.92-7.088,0.913-11.033,0.913-11.033c6.004-17.805,6.309-22.53,3.909-29.24
       c-0.676-1.937-0.847-2.704-0.536-3.545c0.719-1.941,0.195-9.748,1.072-12.848c1.692-5.979,3.361-21.142,4.231-28.217
       c1.169-9.53-4.141-22.308-4.141-22.308c-1.163-5.2,0.542-23.727,0.542-23.727c2.381,3.705,2.29,10.245,2.29,10.245
       c-0.378,6.859,5.541,17.342,5.541,17.342c2.844,4.332,3.921,8.442,3.921,8.747c0,1.248-0.273,4.269-0.273,4.269l0.109,2.631
       c0.049,0.67,0.426,2.977,0.365,4.092c-0.444,6.862,0.646,5.571,0.646,5.571c0.92,0,1.931-5.522,1.931-5.522
       c0,1.424-0.348,5.687,0.42,7.295c0.919,1.918,1.595-0.329,1.607-0.78c0.243-8.737,0.768-6.448,0.768-6.448
       c0.511,7.088,1.139,8.689,2.265,8.135c0.853-0.407,0.073-8.506,0.073-8.506c1.461,4.811,2.569,5.577,2.569,5.577
       c2.411,1.693,0.92-2.983,0.585-3.909c-1.784-4.92-1.839-6.625-1.839-6.625c2.229,4.421,3.909,4.257,3.909,4.257
       c2.174-0.694-1.9-6.954-4.287-9.953c-1.218-1.528-2.789-3.574-3.245-4.789c-0.743-2.058-1.304-8.674-1.304-8.674
       c-0.225-7.807-2.155-11.198-2.155-11.198c-3.3-5.282-3.921-15.135-3.921-15.135l-0.146-16.635
       c-1.157-11.347-9.518-11.429-9.518-11.429c-8.451-1.258-9.627-3.988-9.627-3.988c-1.79-2.576-0.767-7.514-0.767-7.514
       c1.485-1.208,2.058-4.415,2.058-4.415c2.466-1.891,2.345-4.658,1.206-4.628c-0.914,0.024-0.707-0.733-0.707-0.733
       C115.068,0.636,104.01,0,104.01,0h-1.688c0,0-11.063,0.636-9.523,13.089c0,0,0.207,0.758-0.715,0.733
       c-1.136-0.03-1.242,2.737,1.215,4.628c0,0,0.572,3.206,2.058,4.415c0,0,1.023,4.938-0.767,7.514c0,0-1.172,2.73-9.627,3.988
       c0,0-8.375,0.082-9.514,11.429l-0.158,16.635c0,0-0.609,9.853-3.922,15.135c0,0-1.921,3.392-2.143,11.198
       c0,0-0.563,6.616-1.303,8.674c-0.451,1.209-2.021,3.255-3.249,4.789c-2.408,2.993-6.455,9.24-4.29,9.953
       c0,0,1.689,0.164,3.909-4.257c0,0-0.046,1.693-1.827,6.625c-0.35,0.914-1.839,5.59,0.573,3.909c0,0,1.117-0.767,2.569-5.577
       c0,0-0.779,8.099,0.088,8.506c1.133,0.555,1.751-1.047,2.262-8.135c0,0,0.524-2.289,0.767,6.448
       c0.012,0.451,0.673,2.698,1.596,0.78c0.779-1.608,0.429-5.864,0.429-7.295c0,0,0.999,5.522,1.933,5.522
       c0,0,1.099,1.291,0.648-5.571c-0.073-1.121,0.32-3.422,0.369-4.092l0.106-2.631c0,0-0.274-3.014-0.274-4.269
       c0-0.311,1.078-4.415,3.921-8.747c0,0,5.913-10.488,5.532-17.342c0,0-0.082-6.54,2.299-10.245c0,0,1.69,18.526,0.545,23.727
       c0,0-5.319,12.778-4.146,22.308c0.864,7.094,2.53,22.237,4.226,28.217c0.886,3.094,0.362,10.899,1.072,12.848
       c0.32,0.847,0.152,1.627-0.536,3.545c-2.387,6.71-2.083,11.436,3.921,29.24c0,0,1.848,3.945,0.914,11.033
       c0,0-3.836,7.892-1.379,8.05c0,0,0.192,0.523,1.023,0.109c0,0,1.327,1.37,2.761,0.627c0,0,1.328,1.06,2.463,0.116
       c0,0,0.91,1.047,2.237,0.201c0,0,1.742,1.175,2.777-0.098c0,0,1.839,0.408-1.435-7.886c0,0-1.254-8.793-1.945-10.522
       c-1.318-3.275-0.387-12.251-0.106-14.175c0.453-3.216,0.21-8.695-0.618-12.934c-0.606-3.038,1.035-8.774,1.641-12.3
       c1.245-7.423,3.685-26.373,3.38-29.959l1.008,0.354C103.809,118.312,104.265,117.959,104.265,117.959z"
              />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      )
    }
```

On changing the viewbox, say to this

```
function Silhoute({ success }) {
  return (
    <svg
      version="1.1"
      id="Capa_1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px"
      y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 103.163 103.163"
      style={{ enableBackground: "new 0 0 103.163 103.163" }}
      xmlSpace="preserve"
      fill={success ? "#10B981" : "white"}
      className="h-full w-full opacity-50"
    >
      <g>
        <g>
          <path
            d="M104.265,117.959c-0.304,3.58,2.126,22.529,3.38,29.959c0.597,3.52,2.234,9.255,1.645,12.3
   c-0.841,4.244-1.084,9.736-0.621,12.934c0.292,1.942,1.211,10.899-0.104,14.175c-0.688,1.718-1.949,10.522-1.949,10.522
   c-3.285,8.294-1.431,7.886-1.431,7.886c1.017,1.248,2.759,0.098,2.759,0.098c1.327,0.846,2.246-0.201,2.246-0.201
   c1.139,0.943,2.467-0.116,2.467-0.116c1.431,0.743,2.758-0.627,2.758-0.627c0.822,0.414,1.023-0.109,1.023-0.109
   c2.466-0.158-1.376-8.05-1.376-8.05c-0.92-7.088,0.913-11.033,0.913-11.033c6.004-17.805,6.309-22.53,3.909-29.24
   c-0.676-1.937-0.847-2.704-0.536-3.545c0.719-1.941,0.195-9.748,1.072-12.848c1.692-5.979,3.361-21.142,4.231-28.217
   c1.169-9.53-4.141-22.308-4.141-22.308c-1.163-5.2,0.542-23.727,0.542-23.727c2.381,3.705,2.29,10.245,2.29,10.245
   c-0.378,6.859,5.541,17.342,5.541,17.342c2.844,4.332,3.921,8.442,3.921,8.747c0,1.248-0.273,4.269-0.273,4.269l0.109,2.631
   c0.049,0.67,0.426,2.977,0.365,4.092c-0.444,6.862,0.646,5.571,0.646,5.571c0.92,0,1.931-5.522,1.931-5.522
   c0,1.424-0.348,5.687,0.42,7.295c0.919,1.918,1.595-0.329,1.607-0.78c0.243-8.737,0.768-6.448,0.768-6.448
   c0.511,7.088,1.139,8.689,2.265,8.135c0.853-0.407,0.073-8.506,0.073-8.506c1.461,4.811,2.569,5.577,2.569,5.577
   c2.411,1.693,0.92-2.983,0.585-3.909c-1.784-4.92-1.839-6.625-1.839-6.625c2.229,4.421,3.909,4.257,3.909,4.257
   c2.174-0.694-1.9-6.954-4.287-9.953c-1.218-1.528-2.789-3.574-3.245-4.789c-0.743-2.058-1.304-8.674-1.304-8.674
   c-0.225-7.807-2.155-11.198-2.155-11.198c-3.3-5.282-3.921-15.135-3.921-15.135l-0.146-16.635
   c-1.157-11.347-9.518-11.429-9.518-11.429c-8.451-1.258-9.627-3.988-9.627-3.988c-1.79-2.576-0.767-7.514-0.767-7.514
   c1.485-1.208,2.058-4.415,2.058-4.415c2.466-1.891,2.345-4.658,1.206-4.628c-0.914,0.024-0.707-0.733-0.707-0.733
   C115.068,0.636,104.01,0,104.01,0h-1.688c0,0-11.063,0.636-9.523,13.089c0,0,0.207,0.758-0.715,0.733
   c-1.136-0.03-1.242,2.737,1.215,4.628c0,0,0.572,3.206,2.058,4.415c0,0,1.023,4.938-0.767,7.514c0,0-1.172,2.73-9.627,3.988
   c0,0-8.375,0.082-9.514,11.429l-0.158,16.635c0,0-0.609,9.853-3.922,15.135c0,0-1.921,3.392-2.143,11.198
   c0,0-0.563,6.616-1.303,8.674c-0.451,1.209-2.021,3.255-3.249,4.789c-2.408,2.993-6.455,9.24-4.29,9.953
   c0,0,1.689,0.164,3.909-4.257c0,0-0.046,1.693-1.827,6.625c-0.35,0.914-1.839,5.59,0.573,3.909c0,0,1.117-0.767,2.569-5.577
   c0,0-0.779,8.099,0.088,8.506c1.133,0.555,1.751-1.047,2.262-8.135c0,0,0.524-2.289,0.767,6.448
   c0.012,0.451,0.673,2.698,1.596,0.78c0.779-1.608,0.429-5.864,0.429-7.295c0,0,0.999,5.522,1.933,5.522
   c0,0,1.099,1.291,0.648-5.571c-0.073-1.121,0.32-3.422,0.369-4.092l0.106-2.631c0,0-0.274-3.014-0.274-4.269
   c0-0.311,1.078-4.415,3.921-8.747c0,0,5.913-10.488,5.532-17.342c0,0-0.082-6.54,2.299-10.245c0,0,1.69,18.526,0.545,23.727
   c0,0-5.319,12.778-4.146,22.308c0.864,7.094,2.53,22.237,4.226,28.217c0.886,3.094,0.362,10.899,1.072,12.848
   c0.32,0.847,0.152,1.627-0.536,3.545c-2.387,6.71-2.083,11.436,3.921,29.24c0,0,1.848,3.945,0.914,11.033
   c0,0-3.836,7.892-1.379,8.05c0,0,0.192,0.523,1.023,0.109c0,0,1.327,1.37,2.761,0.627c0,0,1.328,1.06,2.463,0.116
   c0,0,0.91,1.047,2.237,0.201c0,0,1.742,1.175,2.777-0.098c0,0,1.839,0.408-1.435-7.886c0,0-1.254-8.793-1.945-10.522
   c-1.318-3.275-0.387-12.251-0.106-14.175c0.453-3.216,0.21-8.695-0.618-12.934c-0.606-3.038,1.035-8.774,1.641-12.3
   c1.245-7.423,3.685-26.373,3.38-29.959l1.008,0.354C103.809,118.312,104.265,117.959,104.265,117.959z"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  )
}
```

The size increases but it has set in a location off screen.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you change width and height (or allow it to fill container) to change size, not the viewBox (unless you're trimming whitespace)

Comment: Use a different viewBox like `viewBox="60 0 90 207"` In order to know the value of the viewBox use the getBBox() method for the path. Remove width and height attributes to let the svg element take the width of the parent element. If you are using `enableBackground` make sure it has the same value as the viewBox

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `width` and an `height` to the svg itself.

You can do it directly inside the `svg` tag, or you can assign a class.

```
<svg width="60px" height="60px">
```

Make sure to match the last two parameters inside `viewBox` with your width and height. You can remove `style="enable-background"` as well.

Comment: Use `style="width: 100%"` in `svg` element.